# How we can adjust long text within div, without changing alignment of page?

Tags: html, css, angular

I don't want to change div tag height and width want to adjust text by using scroll or any other property, for  long text or big paragraph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can add a property `overflow-y:scroll`.

Comment: Hello Sir, I tried that but its extending its height as per text size or sentences

Comment: It will work if you have a fixed height. Give your div a height then it will work properly.